# How to get id value from using angularjs path?

Tags: angularjs

How to get **id** value using angularjs from this path:

```
http://localhost:1234/?id=3333#/Plya/Home
```

Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$location.search()` followed by your parameter you want to get:

```
var paramValue = $location.search().id;
```

This will only work however if you have set `html5mode` to `true` in your config like so:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).config(function($locationProvider) { 
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
});
```

Comment: Completely forgot about that (Guess I am used to having HTML5 mode enabled :)). In non-HTML5 mode $location.search() only returns params after the hashtag. Upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Inject $location into your controller

and then you can use

> $location.search().id

e.g.

```
$scope.id = $location.search().id
```

HTML5 should be enabled for this to work in your case (thanks Chrillewoodz)

In non-HTML5 mode $location.search() only returns params after the hashtag

Comment: do i have to parse the value?

Comment: it;s return me value true

Comment: Check the answer of Chrillewoodz